# No eventlogs from BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, event-log

I've got a new production computer and installed my BizTalk app on there. The problem is that I don't see any messages in the event log, nor from my BizTalk app or BizTalk Server itself. The only message that appears in the event log is the following:

```
The following BizTalk host instance has initialized successfully. 
BizTalk host name: BizTalkServerApplication
Windows service name: BTSSvc$BizTalkServerApplication
```

The source of that message is `BizTalk Server`. And no messages at all, even no logs about errors which I suppose already took place.

Comment: Do you have stuff suspended with errors in BizTalk administrator?

Comment: No, I just don't have event logs

Comment: So how do you know that stuff is not being logged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick thought incase you are still having problems.

I  tried to write to the event log with a source type that didnt already exist and my BizTalk Host user account didn’t have permissions to create a new source type.  This meant I never saw the entry in the event log.

E.g. (from example @Bill Osuch)

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("MyBiztalkApp", "oh i did something");
```

Make sure either the MyBiztalkApp source exists or that your user has permissions on the event log to create it.

Also, if you have a lot of messages going through BizTalk you will probably want to implement your own logging so your event log doesn’t fill up.  We used Log4Net for our implementation and a database to store messages.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not getting any errors (suspended messages) as the messages process, you're not going to see anything in the app log. You could try adding an Expression shape to your orchestration and manually writing out some debug info:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("event type", "whatever...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your application actually use the BiztalkServerApplication host? Check in the Biztalk Administration Console if all the host instances are indeed running. Is your application fully started? Messages are "put on hold" if your receive location is disabled for example.

Answer (score 0):

To check this functionality, write to event log after every operation or shape in BizTalk orchestration.

Scenario-
Suppose you have to assigned a value to xpath of node in a map after transformation so in message assignment shape after you assign some value, you can write eventlog to admin console.

Ex. Suppose we have already initialized  - "orderType" as "PO" in our expression shape and now we have to assign the value of "orderType" to the xpath of a node in our map then-
Shape- MessageAssignment(Under constructMessage Shape after transformation of map)
xpath(msgGetOrderReq, "/*[local-name()='CustomerOrders' and namespace-uri()='http://example.com/EAI/IEmployee/v1.0']/*[local-name()='ordertype' and namespace-uri()='http://example.com/EAI/IEmployee/v1.0']") = ordertype;

Next to this we want to print this information on the admin console so we need to write:-
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("msgGetOrderReq", ordertype, msgGetOrderReq);

Build the project, Deploy and GAC it. Restart the host instance. Run the orchestration, process something and now you will be able to see the logs in admin console.

Regards

Mayank