# No eventlogs from BizTalk applications

Tags: biztalk, event-log, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

I was trying out one functionality of BizTalk from the below link
https://masteringbiztalkserver.wordpress.com/category/pipelines/

Till now I never had to go to event log to check for any entries.
Now when I am trying to get a custom message logged in event Log, from BizTalk application, I dont see any relevent entry from BizTalk other than 2 entries when I restart the BizTalk Host instance.

From my research I had written down the below code in Expression shape in the application Orchestration:

```
xmlMessage = InputMessage;
stringMessage = xmlMessage.OuterXml;
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("BizTalk Server", stringMessage);
```

Here the **InputMessage** is a message defined in orchestration for sample Schema that I have created.

My application got build and deployed properly and it is also processing the messages properly. Its just that I don't see any log in event viewer for my code or for the suspended messages when I intentionally stop the send port.

The discussionfrom below link also didnt help
[No eventlogs from BizTalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666722/no-eventlogs-from-biztalk)
I have BizTalk Server configured on my Windows 7 Ultimate machine. I am the administrator of the machine.

Answer (score 2):

A few points on this:

- BizTalk sever will not log an event for a suspended message, that's why you dont' see one.
- You should never use the BizTalk Server Event Source since the BizTalk product owns that
- You can very easily create you own custom Event Source using PowerShell.

To create a custom Event Source, use something like:

`new-eventlog -logname "Application" -Source "MyApplicationThatLogs"`

To write with this Event Source, use something like:

`System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("MyApplicationThatLogs", "Some Error Occured!", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error, 100, 0);`

Comment: You can actually get BizTalk to send a notification for a suspended message by subscribing to the NACKs on the send port.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` for debugging purposes  I would recommend that you use the [BizTalk CAT Instrumentation Framework](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appfabriccat/2010/08/30/biztalk-application-tracing-made-easy-with-biztalk-cat-instrumentation-framework-controller/).

For a pipeline

```
TraceManager.PipelineComponent.TraceInfo(stringMessage);
```

For a Orchestration

```
Microsoft.BizTalk.CAT.BestPractices.Framework.Instrumentation.TraceManager.WorkflowComponent.TraceInfo(stringMessage);
```

It allows for real-time tracing when needed, "you can enable tracing on a production server with only a negligible impact on performance (when tracing to a file)."